# Using HTML subscript in web.config value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want a substring in a Text, which should be like ABC<sub>2</sub>XYZ

so i used it as below in the web.config where the value is fetched

in Web.config

```
<add key="Name" value="ABC&lt;sub&gt;2 &lt;/sub&gt;XYZ" />
```

in Layout.cshtml

```
<title id="Title">@(string.Format("{0} - {1}", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]), ViewBag.Title))</title>
```

But the final text output shows as ABC< sub>2< /sub>XYZ instead of sub-string. Could you please help me resolve the issue or could you please suggest any-other way of achieving it.

Comment: did you try HttpUtility.HtmlDecode? add the output to a div like `divelement.InnerHtml =  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string);`

Comment: Right, show us how you're outputting the "Name" key.  Are you using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"}

Comment: @techspider I tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode and that didn't work.
 [link] <title id="Title">@(string.Format("{0} - {1}", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]), ViewBag.Title))</title> 'code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the unicode equivalent of subscript 2, '**U+2082**'.

```
<add key="Name" value="ABC&#x2082;XYZ" />
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/

http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information on where you are writing your value on the page.

If you have a `div` tag and wanted to write the value to it, you may do like this:

**In HTML:**

```
 <div id="divTest" runat="server" />
```

**In Code Behind**

```
divTest.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("ABC&lt;sub&gt;2 &lt;/sub&gt;XYZ");
```

if this value is coming from `Web.config`,

```
divTest.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]);
```

Comment: according to the tags, this is an MVC question, not webforms.